# Return Database Name Dynamically

Tags: asp.net

I am using Entity Framework with Asp.net
i need to return database name dynamically from my model 
i using the following code but it return empty string

```
 ResturantEntities db = new ResturantEntities();
        string databaseName = db.Connection.Database;
```

any help thanks

Comment: you must open connection first

Comment: yes i opened connection but steel return empty string

Comment: i need the name of the database dynamically from code behind

Comment: ` ResturantEntities db = new ResturantEntities();
            db.Connection.Open();
            string ConnectionString = db.Connection.Database;
            db.Connection.Close();`